# Dynamic summation of rows using vba

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic

[image: dynamic summation]

- Hi Guys, I need help in my macro, I have 2 sets of dynamic tables which I need to add at the very bottom. But the problem is those 2 sets of data are dynamic
- I have created the macro where those 2 sets of data have summation at the bottom.
- I need a final summation 4 cells down for the 2 sets of data, is this possible?

thanks!

Comment: What have you researched / tried so far? Post your code.

Comment: I tried searching but could not find any that would match, the second comment seems to help but Im still trying to work it out

Answer (score 0):

I mean, there's nothing stopping you from using `=D(X) + D(Y)` which would work perfectly even with dynamic range... Or at least so I would think in the example you provided

---

Though if you absolutely insist on using VBA in this:

*The first two steps are optional, but I'd recommend doing so, because you said that the two tables should be at the bottom, so for sake of consistency and not exceeding table ranges after new data is added, I'd recommend doing them. Also rest of my code presumes, you did change them to tables*

1. Change your "table" ranges into actual Tables (`Insert->Table`)
2. Click on the table, choose the `Design` Tab and edit

   2.1. The Table Name  - to something easy and memorable
   2.2. Add the Total row instead of manually summarizing values in an extra row

   [image]

   *keep in mind, you might likely have to change the way you add data to your table to `ListRow.Add()` as well to keep things consistent*
3. Store the two Totals into variables

   > Code is correct under presumption, your Tables are called "Table1", "Table2" and they are on Worksheet called "Sheet1" and total is in the second column of your table. If not, change accordingly.
4. Output your result somewhere, I printed it in D16, but change that to whereever you want.

Actual code:

```
Private Sub sum_totals()
    Dim sum1 As Long
    Dim sum2 As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    sum1 = ws.ListObjects("Table1").TotalsRowRange(2)
    sum2 = ws.ListObjects("Table2").TotalsRowRange(2)

    ws.Range("D16").Value2 = sum1 + sum2

End Sub
```

Works as expected:

[image]

PS: If you want the result to also be dynamic (eg. 2 rows under the last listrow) then change D16 to `ws.Range(Cells(ws.ListObjects("Table2").TotalsRowRange.Row + 2, "D")).Value2 = sum1 + sum2`

Comment: This code will work for me, I appreciate this, but when i try it the sum returns as "0", I just tested it on a new sheet with all the names as default just like on your code, please help

Comment: how to i add attachement on "add comment" sorry

Comment: @RyanRea you can't. But you can just drop me an url here with the .xlsm file inside and I'll check it later on today

Comment: pardon me for raising your annoying meter, but how do i do it?

Comment: @RyanRea Do what? Upload the file online? Go to  any hosting (or ideally google drive) and upload the file there and give me the url so I can check it. Or what exactly were you trying to attach?

Comment: sorry just got back...https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YRn6LKlv-G-x5mMs0OeXuQMGtC4lCOIU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: morning did you receive the link?